# Ayuda con CORS API NODE JS

Tags: mysql, nodejs, ionic3

Que tal alguien podría ayudarme con los Cors en nodejs, ya estoy utilizando la npm de cors pero no funciona o creo que no las estoy configurando de una forma adecuada, al consumir otras apis que se prestan para el testeo de ellas no ocurre este problema y se ejecutan las sentencias de forma correcta
pd la estoy consumiendo en ionic3

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

//middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors())

app.get('/animales', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!' })
})

app.listen(80, function() {
    console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})

//routes
require('../routes/userRoutes')(app);
require('../routes/ganaRoutes')(app);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server en el puerto 3000');
});
```

Y aqui en la consola de Chrome
[image: arrojo de Chrome]

Answer (score 2):

Nunca he utilizado el paquete de cors, pero yo manejo el  CORS (Control de acceso HTTP) configurando Express de la síguete manera:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');



app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-COntrol-Allow-Request-Method);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
})
```

**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**: Para controlar quien puede consumir mi API

**Access-Control-Allow-Headers**: Para configurar los headers que acepta la API

**Access-Control-Allow-Methods**: Para declarar los métodos que acepta el API

Yo siempre lo he echo así y nunca he tenido inconvenientes, espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias si me funciono, pero descubrí que escribí mal el link jaja